# How to get the current product details in Observer without registey

Tags: magento2, event-observer, registry

How to get the current product in Observer instead of this `"$product = $this->_registry->registry("current_product");"`
I need the code for without registry in the observer.

Comment: On which observer do you want to get this product data?

Answer (score 0):

**try this **

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $productId = $product->getId();
    $productName = $product->getName();
    // You can use the product object to retrieve any other product details you need
}
```